# Anyone know any jQuery plugins for displaying dates in popup calendar?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm looking for a jQuery popup calendar (like the [jQuery UI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)) but I don't want to use it as a date picker, only as a calendar to show that certain dates have been booked (using some styling to highlight each date, the way outlook does in the month view).

Does anyone know of any plugins that can do this?  I've had a hunt but can only find plugins for datepickers, not for displaying data.

I could modify the jQuery UI Datepicker for this purpose but was wondering if anyone knows of anything that I can pick up and run with rather than having to do a lot of tinkering with an existing plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know [this one](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/). Pretty straightforward.

Comment: This will be ideal with a little styling. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can UI Datepicker for that as well. Check [this example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#inline). It shows UI Datepicker as a calendar not as a date picker. You can then easily change the styles of the values you want to highlight. There're tons of options in this plugin so I don't think you need to modify it just configure it for your needs.

Comment: I was hoping for something that would take a json object of dates to be highlighted but I suppose I could travers the DOM and set style that way.